# How to import a file in the same folder in python?

Tags: python

My directory structure is as follows;

```
ATGWS
  |-models
      |-SiteConfig.py
      |-__init__.py
  |-atgws.py
  |-CustomEncoder.py
  |-__init__.py
```

I want to call customencoder.py within atgws.py.
i try like this;

```
from CustomEncoder import CustomEncoder

..
app.json_encoder = CustomEncoder
```

but not working.

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ratha/projects/test711/ATGWS/atgws.py", line 3, in <module>
    from CustomEncoder import CustomEncoder
ImportError: cannot import name CustomEncoder
```

How can i call this?

Comment: There is no file named CustomJsonEncoder in your hierarchy, try `from CustomEncoder import CustomJsonEncoder`.

Comment: @MatsLindh Sorry CustomEncoder

Comment: Place an `__init__.py` file in the ATGWS directory.

Comment: @Darkonaut I did but same issue

Comment: post the traceback please

Comment: @Darkonaut I added traceback error

Comment: from .CustomEncoder import CustomEncoder

Comment: @BUZZY now getting     from .CustomEncoder import CustomEncoder 
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: the last point in `CustomEncoder.py.` from your directory sketch is just a typo here or did you name the file in real that way?

Comment: @Darkonaut sorry typo here, corrected

Comment: Is there anything called `CustomEncoder` within the file `CustomEncoder` at all?

Comment: @Darkonaut Yes class name is same as file name.//class CustomJEncoder(JSONEncoder):

Comment: You main-script is `atgws.py` or from where do you start execution?

Comment: @Darkonaut it is atgws.py

Comment: try just importing the module, `import CustomEncoder` does this also fail?

Comment: @Darkonaut in that case I get following error //    app.json_encoder = CustomEncoder
NameError: name 'CustomEncoder' is not defined
//

Comment: How are you running this application? Check `sys.path` whether this package is reachable.

Comment: @Darkonaut i fixed it posted my answer

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like

```
from CustomEncoder import CustomEncoder
..
app.json_encoder = CustomJSONEncoder()
```

Works.